# NSManagedObjectController (like a NSFetchRequestController for single NSManagedObject)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

NSManagedObjectController doesn't seem to exist, but maybe its called something else... 
NSFetchRequestController fetches multiple NSManagedObjects and lists them in a UITableView. But is there an already existing class that will show the attributes of an NSManagedObject and list them in a UITableView of style == UITableViewStyleGrouped. Maybe using the localized property names in the NSManagedObjectModel as the section header names, and the values of the properties as a single row of that section? Hopefully this magical thing could look at the data-types of the attributes of the NSManagedObject to add UITextField to cell rows of data-types NSString, NSNumber, etc, and UIDatePicker to cell rows of data-type NSDate, and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there an already existing class that will show the attributes of an
>   NSManagedObject and list them in a UITableView of style ==
>   UITableViewStyleGrouped

No, Cocoa Touch doesn't provide a class that matches that description. It doesn't sound difficult to write, but the value seems questionable. I can see a use for exploring a data model during development, but the user interface you describe seems unlikely to be useful in a production app, where one probably wouldn't want interface elements like labels tied so strongly to model property names and some properties might not be meant for display at all.

However, if you need such a beast, it won't be hard to build. Use `NSEntityDescription` to get the property names. For example, you can use `attributesByName` to get a dictionary of attribute names and descriptions.